# Center a textview vertical to a EditText

Tags: android, textview, android-layout, android-edittext, android-relativelayout

What I'm trying to do is have a TextView, and to the right of it an editText that takes up the rest of the space.  The textView should be  centered vertically along the editText.  Now I can do this using an linearlayout, however I would prefer to do it in a relativelayout.

```
<RelativeLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:padding="10dp">
     <TextView
          android:id="@+id/loginText"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Login:"
          android:paddingRight="20dp" />

<EditText
          android:id="@+id/login"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_toRightOf="@id/loginText" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

What you want to do is possible by using the [`android:layout_alignBottom`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android%3alayout_alignBottom) and [`android:layout_alignTop`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android%3alayout_alignBottom) properties provided by the `RelativeLayout` to its children and the [`android:gravity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3agravity) property of the `TextView`.

These properties allow you to set the bottom/top edge of a view to match the bottom/top edge of another view. By applying them to the `TextView` you can effectively make the `TextView` match the height of the `EditText` control. Then, with the gravity property you can make the text in the `TextView` center vertically inside the `TextView` control.

The following example should work as you intended:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp" >
    <TextView android:id="@+id/user_name_label"
        android:text="@string/user_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp" 
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/user_name_text"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/user_name_text"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" />
    <EditText android:id="@id/user_name_text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/user_name_label" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

add `android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"` to your Textview

this would place the textview centered vertically in the parent

---

Comment: that would work if the height of the textview was the same height as an editText.  This is not the case however.

Comment: can you set both the edittext and textview to have a layout_gravity="center_vertical" ? would that do the trick ?